# Remove brackets and single quotes from REGEX result

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Im new to python.  I need my regex to return without the surrounding brackets and single quotes

Right now it returns: **['UP-3415']**

I want it to return: **UP-3415**

Below is my code.

```
import re

str = "I need to extract UP-3415 from this string"
result = re.findall('UP-[0-9]{4}', str)
print(result)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: print(result[0]), findall returns an array(list), []

Answer (score 2):

re.findall returns all match results with List. So you can use that value with 
`result[0]`
Or try using `re.search`

```py
import re

str = "I need to extract UP-3415 from this string"
result = re.search('UP-[0-9]{4}', str)
print(result) # <re.Match object; span=(18, 25), match='UP-3415'>
print(result.group(0)) # UP-3415
```

Comment: Thanks.  I will do it wit the search and group just like in your example :)